# How to do a every 3 months cron job in laravel?

Tags: laravel, cron

I am using laravel to schedule a job to run every 3 months at 2am, so I created:

$schedule->command('clean:market-history')->cron( '0 0 0,2 ? 1/3 * *');

But according to my research (by using: [this reference](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html#)) this indicates it will run every 3 months **starting** in January at 2 am. I got most of it right, I do want it to run every three months at 2 am, but if it starts in January does that not mean if I deploy in august, for example, that it wont start running till January?

Some resources stated to use: `*/3` how ever, the site, linked above, states the same, starting in January at 2 am.

Is this correct or am I missing something? Can some one explain?

Comment: check this out: `https://crontab.guru/#0_0,2_*_8/3_*`

Comment: @TheWebs no, it is saying that it will count 3 months starting on January, so it is going to happen on January and on, every 3 months...You could say every 3 months starting on May, but you don't want that, you want it to be since the first day of the year and on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run your command quarterly (First day of Jan, April, July, October) you can use Laravel's pre-canned quarterly function:

```
$schedule->command('YourCommandHere')->quarterly('02:00')->timezone('America/New_York');
```

If you want to run this command every three months starting from time of implementation (ie every 3 months starting now) you can use Laravel's cron function that lets you pass a custom cron line and that cron line would look like this:

```
$schedule->command('YourCommandHere')->cron('0 2 * */3 *')->timezone('America/New_York');
```

You can configure any iteration of laravel's cron function.  Just use the crontab.guru reference I shared below.  It's a lifesaver.  Also, don't forgot to define timezone as I do if you intend on using a different timezone than what the server is set to.

To get all of the Laravel schedule features review this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

My most frequently used url to identify what my cron line should look like:  [https://crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_2_*_*/3_*)

Comment: Useful is the  last link you shared